# Angular2 Final: es2015.core.d.ts:17:14: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'

Tags: angular, ionic2

Any idea how to debug this? This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented out **lib**:

```
// "lib": [
//        "dom",
//        "es2015"
//    ]
```

This is against Ionic 2 Best practice, but this is how it works. I would be interested in knowing why. I have a clue that it is conflicting with some overseen artefacts of my previous typings installation.